# The best way to simplify keras codes in a loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to create a list that can save different settings of layers, so that it can be merged later, here is the original code

```
_conv = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=[32,1])(_input)
_norm = BatchNormalization()(_conv)
_activ = Activation("relu")(_norm)
_maxpool_1 = MaxPooling2D()(_activ)

_conv = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=[32,2])(_input)
_norm = BatchNormalization()(_conv)
_activ = Activation("relu")(_norm)
_maxpool_2 = MaxPooling2D()(_activ)

_conv = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=[32,3])(_input)
_norm = BatchNormalization()(_conv)
_activ = Activation("relu")(_norm)
_maxpool_3 = MaxPooling2D()(_activ)

_conv = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=[32,4])(_input)
_norm = BatchNormalization()(_conv)
_activ = Activation("relu")(_norm)
_maxpool_4 = MaxPooling2D()(_activ)

merged_tensor = concatenate([_maxpool_1, _maxpool_2, _maxpool_3, _maxpool_4])
```

as you can see that they are all the same except for the kernel sizes, so in order to simplify the code, can i create something like this? (basically a loop and a list)

```
_maxpool_list=[]
for i in range(1,5):
    _conv = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=[32,i])(_input)
    _norm = BatchNormalization()(_conv)
    _activ = Activation("relu")(_norm)
    _maxpool_list.append((MaxPooling2D()(_activ))

merged_tensor = concatenate(_maxpool_list)
```

or, my question can be, what's the best way to create a list of keras layers, so that i can load all of them later

Comment: `_maxpool_list.append(MaxPooling2D()(_activ))`?

Comment: yea, thank, sorry that was a mistyping, i have corrected that

Answer (score 2):

```
def applyLayerGroup(kernelSize, _input):
    _conv = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=[32,kenelSize], padding='same')(_input)
    _norm = BatchNormalization()(_conv)
    _activ = Activation("relu")(_norm)
    _maxpool = MaxPooling2D()(_activ)

    return _maxpool

sizes = [1,2,3,4]
_maxpool_list= [getLayerGroup(size,_input) for size in sizes]
merged_tensor = Concatenate()(_maxpool_list)
```

---

Added `padding='same'` to avoid a bug. (Credits to @user36624)

Comment: one more thing, make sure `padding=same`. Otherwise, you will have the problem in concatenation due to the different output sizes.